# Why is $d(f,f_n)=1/2$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble fully understanding this:

For the sequence

$f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

on the interval [0,1], the limit function is

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}{1\over2}&\text{ if }x=1 \\ 0&\text{ if }x\neq 1\end{array}\right.$$

I am having trouble understanding why $\sup\{|f_n-f|\}$ is $1/2$, even though I've read the answers on this old thread: [Uniform convergence with two limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651041/uniform-convergence-with-two-limits).

I think the argument goes:
If you let $x\rightarrow 1$, you get $f_n=0$ because $f_n$ doesn't take the value of $1/2$ until $x$ is exactly 1. But $f(1)=1/2$ so the supremum is $1/2$. Is this correct?

I just don't understand this argument, because if you let $x\rightarrow1$, isn't $f$ also $0$, for the same reason as $f_n$? (And therefore the supremum should be $0$?).

I hope someone can understand my confusion and perhaps take me through all the steps of showing that the distance is $1/2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: (guessing) because your wording is a bit confusing. Quantities such as $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ are not defined (though it's safe to assume that you mean the sup-norm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $n$. Note that 
$$
f_{n}(1)=\frac{1^{n}}{1+1^{n}}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Since $f_{n}$ is continuous, it follows that there is a sequence
$(x_{m})_{m}$ such that $0\leq x_{m}<1$ for all $n$, $x_{m}\rightarrow1$,
and $f_{n}(x_{m})\rightarrow1/2$. However, $f(x_{m})=0$. Therefore,
we have
$$
\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_{n}-f\right|\geq\sup_{m}\left|f_{n}(x_{m})-f(x_{m})\right|=\sup_{m}\left|f_{n}(x_{m})\right|=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

As for the reverse direction of the inequality, note that 
$$
f_{n}^{\prime}(x)=\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{2}}
$$
so that $f_{n}$ is nondecreasing on $[0,1]$. Moreover, $f_{n}(0)=0$
and $f_{n}(1)=1/2$ (as shown above).

Comment: I think I understand now and I think I got $f_n$ and $f$ mixed up before. This is how I intuitively understand it now and please correct me if I'm wrong: Because $f_n$ is continuous, there is a point just before $x=1$, in which $f_n$ will be (almost) 1/2. But the limit function is defined piecewise, the limit function will say that the value is still 0. Therefore the distance between them will be (almost) 1/2. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct; good work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!